# Check If a Column Exists in Laravel Migration File

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Already I have a table name `table_one.` Now I want to add two more columns to it. Everything works fine so far. But in my method, I want to check a column exists or not in my table like `dropIfExists('table').`

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('column_one')->nullable();
        $table->string('column_two')->nullable();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // in here i want to check column_one and column_two exists or not
        $table->dropColumn('column_one');
        $table->dropColumn('column_two');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You need something just like this

```
  public function down()
    {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('users', 'phone'))
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->dropColumn('phone');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked fine. But i didn't like the approach. I wanted something like dropIfExists('column').

Comment: Don't forget to install doctrine/dbal package.

Answer (score 12):

You could make your own 'dropColumnIfExists()' function that checks the column existence then drop it:

```
function myDropColumnIfExists($myTable, $column)
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn($myTable, $column)) //check the column
    {
        Schema::table($myTable, function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn($column); //drop it
        });
    }

}
```

And use it on 'down()' function like this:

```
public function down()
{
    myDropColumnIfExists('table_one', 'column_two');
    myDropColumnIfExists('table_one', 'column_one');
}
```

Comment: Please always provide some explanations and not just a piece of code.

Comment: this will def through an error on $table->dropColumn($column) statement , since you havent passed the arg $column , it should be like 
Schema::table($myTable, function (Blueprint $table) use ($column).....

Answer (score 4):

For dynamically checking your table column you can try something like this:

```
public function dropIfExists($table, $column)
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn($table, $column)) //check the column
    {
        Schema::table($table, function (Blueprint $table) use ($column)
        {
            $table->dropColumn($column); //drop it
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want it inside the `Schema::table` closure, which is the only neat way to do it... you would either need to add a couple of methods to `Blueprint`, or use this boilerplate inside every migration... it's not pretty, but once it's there you can define as many conditional add and drop's as you like, using only 1 line each.

```php
return new class extends Migration {
    public function up() {

        Schema::table('tblAnimal', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $exists = function (string $column) use ($table) {
                return (Schema::hasColumn($table->getTable(), $column));
            };
            $addUnlessExists = function (string $type, string $name, array $parameters = [])
                use ($table, $exists) {
                    return $exists($name) ? null : $table->addColumn($type, $name, $parameters);
                };
            $dropIfExists = function (string $column) use ($table, $exists) {
                return $exists($column) ? $table->dropColumn($column) : null;
            };

            $dropIfExists('column_name');
            $addUnlessExists('integer', 'int_column');
            # ...
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a function like this

```
public function dropColumnIfExists($tbl,$column)
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn($tbl, $column)) {
        Schema::table($tbl, function (Blueprint $table) use ($column) {
            $table->dropColumn($column);
        });
    }
}
```

and call it in the up or down function like this (Considering as up function)

```
public function up()
{
    $tbl = 'table_name';
    Schema::table($tableName, function (Blueprint $table) use ($tbl) {
        $this->dropColumnIfExists($tbl,'your_colomn_name');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Great discussion! Here is a callable approach with multi DB support.

Keep it DRY & clean with a Trait:

```
namespace App\Support\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

trait HasManyConnections
{

    /**
     * Runs a migration conditionally if specified columns do not already exist
     *
     * @param string $connection
     *
     * @param string $table
     * @param mixed $columns
     * @param callable $callback
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function runIfColumnsAreNew(string $connection, string $table, $columns, callable $callback) : void
    {
        $schema = Schema::connection($connection);
        
        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Create the table and run the migration if the table doesn't exist
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        if(!$schema->hasTable($table)){

            $schema->create($table, function (Blueprint $table) use ($callback){

                $callback($table);
            });

            return;
        }

        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Iterate the provided columns and determine if any exist
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $migratable = true;

        Collection::wrap($columns)->each(function($column) use ($schema, $table, &$migratable){

            if($migratable){

                $migratable = !$schema->hasColumn($table, $column);
            }
        });

        /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Update the table if all columns are new
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        if ($migratable) {

            $schema->table($table, function (Blueprint $table) use ($callback){

                $callback($table);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now we treat it like a standard migration passing our logic in to the closure.

```
use App\Support\Concerns\HasManyConnections;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    use HasManyConnections;

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        $this->runIfColumnsAreNew('accounts_db', 'profiles', 'squad_name', function(Blueprint $table){
           
            $table->string('squad_name')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        //
    }
};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: what if we need to drop a column

like we need to drop and add few columns and vice versa in down() method
in down() method we'll add those columns right??

Answer (score -14):

Just break the schema up into two calls

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['column_one', 'column_two']);
    });

    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('column_one')->nullable();
        $table->string('column_two')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Comment: This will cause all the data in these columns to be deleted too! Very dangerous code!

Comment: Not a good approach